# Submit a form and see output not only at the end of php code

Tags: php, forms, loops, buffer, echo

When submitting a form, the `php` code is executed, and at the end of the `php code` the output is displayed on the screen.

I have a form that, when sent, submit a large amount of mails with a `foreach`.
Every mail the php code sends (so every loop of the foreach), an `echo` with a `success` or `error` is displayed.

The problem is that all `echos` are displayed only once the php has sent all mails.

So between the form submit and the output I have about 60-90 seconds of waiting with anything.

Is it possible to output the code to the user screen not when all the code is executed but while the loop is working?

Thank you.

Comment: Your strategy is not suitable for what you are trying to do. Take a look around for job schedulers, or if you really want to code that in php, then get familiar with js/ajax to work in an asynchronous way.

Comment: Yes, I thought at the AJAX solution, but before changing all the code, I wanted to ask if this was possible with a normal form submit

Comment: Many people made many tries , found many half working solutions and wasted many many days. php, or scripts on the web in general, are not made for this. Too many issues outside of what you can control, like browser caches, proxies and and and

Comment: So AJAX solution is the best way to do this in php/javascript? Which other ways (schedulers) are there?